# Unity - how to make a STRETCHY rope?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

Ok, Ive looked thru the asset store and tried out the Wrapping Rope high rated asset, however the asset could not provide the effect I need -

How/What is the simplest way to implement a STRETCHY rope in Unity? Where an object can hang from it vertically, and if the user pulls down, the rope will stretch.When they let go, it will bounce back up into place

Ive gone through some hinge/joint rope tutorials however they aren't geared to this functionality - how can I get a stretchy rope?

EDIT: ok I followed this guys tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4YCj4Tid0w and have something working but it isn't 3d when you look closely, also too stretchy/never stops bouncing:

[image]

Comment: You may try use Spring, and then add meshes as bone of the spring, make the mesh pieces a bit longer so no gap will come out when you stretch.

Comment: Is that an asset? Can you provide a link?

Comment: No...not asset, just the spring joint, in component -> Physics 2D/3D

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: take a look at [Hooke's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law). It's pretty straightforward and well behaved math, it would'nt be that hard to implement. If you want to add bouncing I'd suggest you to do it *fake¨, like in a predeterminated way, as a physically accurate bouncing would take into account oscilation and dampness, and that would make hte math harder

Comment: do you have any examples?

Comment: PS: this is not the intended usage of the tag `rope` in SO